# Oozie Coordinator Jobs are getting killed automatically without much information

Tags: bigdata, oozie

Oozie Coordinators in Prod environment are automatically getting killed with below logs:

Till 27th Aug Everything has run fine, on 28th Aug 09:00 the job is scheduled to run but job gets killed 20mins before scheduled run.

```
2023-08-27 10:06:00,005 TRACE CallableQueueService:529 - SERVER[hdp0117.global] USER[myuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[app-myapp] JOB[0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[] poll(): [coord_action_input_0031677-230627122031098-oozie-oozi-C@1124], from P[1]

2023-08-28 08:40:39,360 TRACE CoordKillXCommand:529 - SERVER[0116.global] USER[myuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[app-app-myapp] JOB[0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[-] Precondition check for command [coord_kill] key [0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C]

2023-08-28 08:40:39,360 DEBUG CoordKillXCommand:526 - SERVER[0116.global] USER[myuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[app-app-myapp] JOB[0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[-] Execute command [coord_kill] key [0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C]

2023-08-28 08:40:39,361 DEBUG CoordKillXCommand:526 - SERVER[0116.global] USER[myuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[app-myapp] JOB[0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[-] Killed coord actions for the coordinator=[0033644-230729144752906-oozie-oozi-C]
```

End Time is configured as 3000-01-01.

```
<coordinator-app name="${appName}"
                 frequency="${jobFrequency}"
                 start="${startTime}"
                 end="${endTime}"
                 timezone="UTC"
                 xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.5">

    <controls>
        <concurrency>1</concurrency>
        <throttle>1</throttle>
    </controls>

    <datasets>
        <dataset name="output_dataset" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
                 initial-instance="${initialDatasetInstance}" timezone="UTC">
            <uri-template>
                ${oozieTriggerFileLocation}/${moduleName}/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}/
            </uri-template>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>

    <output-events>
        <data-out name="output_events" dataset="output_dataset">
            <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-out>
    </output-events>

    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${codePath}</app-path>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>today</name>
                    <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd")}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>yesterday</name>
                    <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1, 'DAY'),'yyyy-MM-dd')}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>nominalTime</name>
                    <value>${coord:nominalTime()}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```